# UPDATE, with CASE statement, ignoring NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server

My code below isn't performing well on my attempt to update a table with a little more than 100,000 rows.

I have about 2500 values in which the first value in a sequence is NULL, as a result that row and the following sequences are not getting updated.

Additionally, about 5000 rows are also not updating because they do not exist in the second of the two tables (table 1 = dbo.abc / table 2 = dbo.abc_d)

Regarding the second issue, I can write a second query just for that table, but I am stuck on the first issue. If you have any advice on improving this query for either issue it would be appreciated.

```
UPDATE dbo.abc abc
SET    vcn1 = ( CASE
                  WHEN abc.chan_id1 IS NOT NULL THEN abc.chan_id1
                  WHEN abc.chan_id2 IS NOT NULL THEN abc.chan_id2
                  WHEN abc.chan_id3 IS NOT NULL THEN abc.chan_id3
                  --omitting this chuck for readability
                  WHEN abc_d.chan_id34 IS NOT NULL THEN abc_d.chan_id34
                  WHEN abc_d.chan_id35 IS NOT NULL THEN abc_d.chan_id35
                  WHEN abc_d.chan_id36 IS NOT NULL THEN abc_d.chan_id36
                END ),
       vcn2 = ( CASE
                  WHEN abc.chan_id1 IS NOT NULL AND abc.chan_id1 != abc.vcn1 THEN abc.chan_id1
                  WHEN abc.chan_id2 IS NOT NULL AND abc.chan_id2 != abc.vcn1 THEN abc.chan_id2
                  WHEN abc.chan_id3 IS NOT NULL AND abc.chan_id3 != abc.vcn1 THEN abc.chan_id3
                  --omitting this chuck for readability
                  WHEN abc_d.chan_id34 IS NOT NULL AND abc_d.chan_id34 != abc.vcn1 THEN abc_d.chan_id34
                  WHEN abc_d.chan_id35 IS NOT NULL AND abc_d.chan_id35 != abc.vcn1 THEN abc_d.chan_id35
                  WHEN abc_d.chan_id36 IS NOT NULL AND abc_d.chan_id36 != abc.vcn1 THEN abc_d.chan_id36
                END )
FROM   dbo.abc_d abc_d
WHERE  abc.abc_id = abc_d.abc_id;
```

Comment: Your problem is not clear I think. Anyway, wouldn't it be simpler if you replaced those case when .... end with Coalesce(abc.chan_id1, abc.chan_id2, abc.chan_id3, ... abc_d.chan_id34 ...) BTW, for second issue you could use a left join.

Comment: The syntax you have there isn't valid; you can't alias a table in the `UPDATE` clause. The above would generate the error `Incorrect syntax near 'abc'.` Also, it's a `CASE` **expression**; it returns a scalar value.

Comment: Your real issue is the lack of normalization: you shouldn't have 36 identical columns

Comment: @Charlieface, the database I have inherited is a mess... many tables with multiple identical columns like I have in this issue. Can you point me to any resources that might set me on a path to correcting this database?

Comment: Maybe start here https://www.sqlshack.com/what-is-database-normalization-in-sql-server/ there should be plenty online if you use Google

Answer (score 1):

You can use a left join to solve your second issue. Your first issue is not an issue:

```
UPDATE dbo.abc
SET    vcn1 = coalesce( abc.chan_id1, 
                        abc.chan_id2, 
                        abc_d.chan_id34,
                        abc_d.chan_id35
                ),
       vcn2 = ( CASE
                  WHEN abc.chan_id1 IS NOT NULL AND abc.chan_id1 != abc.vcn1 THEN abc.chan_id1
                  WHEN abc.chan_id2 IS NOT NULL AND abc.chan_id2 != abc.vcn1 THEN abc.chan_id2
                  WHEN abc_d.chan_id34 IS NOT NULL AND abc_d.chan_id34 != abc.vcn1 THEN abc_d.chan_id34
                  WHEN abc_d.chan_id35 IS NOT NULL AND abc_d.chan_id35 != abc.vcn1 THEN abc_d.chan_id35
                END )
FROM  dbo.abc abc 
left join dbo.abc_d abc_d
on  abc.abc_id = abc_d.abc_id;
```

Here is [DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cff08589083dcf8140cd68c20ef11f1b)

Comment: Hello Cetin. I will upgrade my SQL knowledge and try out the coalesce option. Thank you. Could I also use the coalesce in the second case statement (VCN2)?

Comment: @RichardConaway, well in second case there is a more complex comparison, which actually I think is not correct, but I simply followed your expression. Coalesce() doesn't seem to be a direct fit there, but I really didn't understand what you are trying to set there. Check the DbFiddle sample. When VCN1 is NULL, match fails anyway and VCN2 is NULL at the end. Probably instead you meant something like: vcn2 = ( CASE
                  WHEN abc.chan_id1 IS NOT NULL AND (abc.vcn1 is null or abc.chan_id1 != abc.vcn1) THEN abc.chan_id1
                  WHEN ...

Comment: FWIW `abc.chan_id1 IS NOT NULL AND abc.chan_id1 != abc.vcn1` the `NULL` check here is not needed as for the [in]equality check to result in `true` it _has to be non-null_!